# C# SFTP - download file corrupted and showing different size when compare the file SFTP server

Tags: c#, sftp

I am trying to download .zip and .xlsx files from SFTP server,after downloading when I tried to open the zip file, it saying the compressed zip files is invalid and also the files size is high compared with the SFTP file size(remote file size). 
I am using the below code :

```
    string sFTPHost = "sftphost";
    string sFTPDirectory = "file.zip";
    string sFTPUser = "username";
    string sFTPPassword = "pwd";
    string sFTPPort = "22";

    ConnectionInfo ConnNfo = new ConnectionInfo(@sFTPHost, Convert.ToInt32(sFTPPort), @sFTPUser,
        new AuthenticationMethod[]{
            new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(@sFTPUser,@sFTPPassword),
        }
    );

    using (var sftp = new SftpClient(ConnNfo))
    {
        sftp.Connect();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        sftp.DownloadFile(@sFTPDirectory, ms);
        byte[] feedData = ms.GetBuffer();

        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="filename.zip");
        response.AddHeader("Content-Length", feedData.Length.ToString());
        response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        response.BinaryWrite(feedData);
        sftp.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: My bet would be that it's because a `.zip` file is binary, and the default FTP mode is ANSI (text), and that the server is Linux but you're on Windows (or vice versa), and the file is having the CR/LF changed because of the difference between the two OSes line ending characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MemoryStream.GetBuffer` returns the underlying array of the stream which can/will contain **allocated, unused bytes**. For example the length of the returned *buffer* will match the stream's current `Capacity`, but will most likely be **larger** than the stream's current `Length`.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer?view=netcore-3.1#remarks):

> Note that the buffer contains allocated bytes which might be unused.
>   For example, if the string "test" is written into
>   the MemoryStream object, the length of the buffer returned
>   from GetBuffer is 256, not 4, with 252 bytes unused.

You will need to use `ToArray` instead. Note however that this creates a new array and copies the data into it.

```
byte[] feedData = ms.ToArray();
var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.zip");
response.AddHeader("Content-Length", feedData.Length.ToString());
response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
response.BinaryWrite(feedData);
```

Alternatively you *should* be able to copy from one stream to the other:

```
var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.zip");
response.AddHeader("Content-Length", ms.Length.ToString());
response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

// rewind stream and copy to response
ms.Position = 0;
ms.CopyTo(response.OutputStream);
```